# How to use Magento with custom html/css layout

Tags: php, laravel, api, magento2, headless-cms

I want to use `Magento` as a backend/admin panel, but with my own frontend, which I made in `Laravel`.

I've looked for resources online about making custom Magento themes but the articles I've found have been more about styling the already-made Magento frontend structure rather than completely replacing it with my own.

The closest I've found was a mention of using Magento as a headless API but I don't know how I'd get started with that.

Comment: use Magento over the api like this project, https://github.com/michaelkmartin/laravel-magento-integration

Answer (score 0):

For styling Magento frontend it is some kind of different compare to other frontends because you have layout and blocks and ...

Making headless project is good choice and use Magento az backend will be awsome .

Actually we have worked in a project it was headless ; Magento as backend and React as it's frontend , they interacted with graphql together .

You can interact with Magento in every way you want ; Rest api or Graphql api , it's up to you .

so for conclude to handling Magento in backend you should know about Magento structure to write API and then you're ready to start .

You can start it by it's documentation :
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).